# Can I assign preset bookmarks for a page in Adobe?

Tags: pdf, bookmarks

Is there a method - without merging several .pdf files into one .pdf file - to preset bookmarks for Adobe?

After I am done scanning my pages, I would like to be able to assign a pre-named bookmark to a page.

Comment: ... and by "Adobe", you mean Acrobat? Or what, specifically?